# Bayesian updating - How to update?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Consider that we have two sets of dices. One set contains fair dices while the other set contains dices in which the probability of $6$ is $1/2$. The fair dices correspond to $99\%$ of the whole sample, which means the loaded dices occur with a frequency of $1\%$.

If I pick a dice at random and throw 3 sixes in a row, what is the probability that I have a loaded dice?

It is clear that Bayes rule can be applied:

$$
P( \mathrm{Loaded} \, | \, \mathrm{3 six} ) =
\frac{ P( \mathrm{3 six} \, | \, \mathrm{Loaded} ) P ( \mathrm{Loaded} ) }{ P( \mathrm{3 six} )}
$$

my question however is about the prior probability. After I've thrown one six, I can update my beliefs whether the die is loaded or not. Do I use $P(\mathrm{Loaded}) = 1/100$ or $P(\mathrm{Loaded}) = P( \mathrm{Loaded} \, |\,  \mathrm{2 six})$, which to be computed needs
$P(\mathrm{Loaded} \, | \, \mathrm{1 six})$?

These give different results. What is their interpretation? Which has the correct interpretation as probability of having a loaded die?

This calculation is an example in the book *Richard Durbin, Sean R. Eddy, Anders Krogh, Graeme Mitchison - Biological Sequence Analysis - Probabilistic Models of Proteins and Nucleic Acids - Cambridge University Press (1999)* in section 1.3. They compute $P(\mathrm{Loaded} \, | \, \mathrm{3 six})$ using directly $P(\mathrm{Loaded}) = 0.01$. They do not compute the probability of obtaining one six, then proceed to use that as a prior for the probability of obtaining two sixes, and so on.
Is their procedure wrong? What is exactly what they are computing?

Comment: I find your last paragraph a bit hard to follow.  You would update the probability after rolling the first $6$.  You would use this posterior probability as the prior to update the probability after the second $6$.  You would use the new posterior as the prior to update the probability after the third $6$.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: You say that I have to update the prior after every throw that I make. This does answer my question. The book that I was following didn't. I wanted to know if they are wrong or I am.

Comment: What exactly does the book say?  You can update after each roll, or update after all three.  Both should give the same answer.  Again, I can't understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I did it both ways and got the same answer.

Comment: What did you do? If you could post it as an answer, I'd appreciate it. Also, I edited the question. Hope that I clarified your concerns, if not then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's update it three times.  Let $L$ be the event that we chose the loaded die, and let $S$ be the event that we roll a $6$.

For the first update:

$$\Pr(L|S)=\frac{\Pr(L\wedge S)}{\Pr(S)}=\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac1{100}}{\frac1{100}\cdot\frac12+\frac{99}{100}\cdot\frac16}=\frac1{34}$$

In the second update, we use $\frac1{34}$ as the prior.

$$\Pr(L|S)=\frac{\Pr(L\wedge S)}{\Pr(S)}=\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac1{34}}{\frac1{34}\cdot\frac12+\frac{33}{34}\cdot\frac16}=\frac1{12}$$

We do the same thing a third time, using $\frac1{12}$ as the prior:

$$\Pr(L|S)=\frac{\Pr(L\wedge S)}{\Pr(S)}=\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac1{12}}
{\frac1{12}\cdot\frac12+\frac{11}{12}\cdot\frac16}=\frac3{14}$$

The posterior probability that the die is loaded is $\frac3{14}.$

Alternatively, we just update once.  Let $S_3$ be the event that we roll three consecutive sixes.

$$\Pr(L|S_3)=\frac{\Pr(L\wedge S_3)}{\Pr(S)}=\frac{\frac18\cdot\frac1{100}}{\frac1{100}\cdot\frac18+\frac{99}{100}\cdot\frac1{216}}=\frac3{14},$$

the same answer as before.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, I didn't realize both were actually equal. And I found the mistake in my calculations.

Comment: @OkThen Glad to help.